# Grid-search with specific validation data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

I'm looking for a way to grid-search for hyperparameters in sklearn, without using K-fold validation. I.e I want my grid to train on on specific dataset (X1,y1 in the example below) and validate itself on specific hold-out dataset (X2,y2  in the example below).

X1,y2 = train data
X2,y2 = validation data

```
clf_ = SVC(kernel='rbf',cache_size=1000)
Cs = [1,10.0,50,100.0,]
Gammas = [ 0.4,0.42,0.44,0.46,0.48,0.5,0.52,0.54,0.56]
clf = GridSearchCV(clf_,dict(C=Cs,gamma=Gammas),
                 cv=???, # validate on X2,y2
                 n_jobs=8,verbose=10)
clf.fit(X1, y1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `hypopt` Python package (`pip install hypopt`). It's a professional package created specifically for parameter optimization with a validation set. It works with any scikit-learn model out-of-the-box and can be used with Tensorflow, PyTorch, Caffe2, etc. as well.

```
# Code from https://github.com/cgnorthcutt/hypopt
# Assuming you already have train, test, val sets and a model.
from hypopt import GridSearch
param_grid = [
  {'C': [1, 10, 100], 'kernel': ['linear']},
  {'C': [1, 10, 100], 'gamma': [0.001, 0.0001], 'kernel': ['rbf']},
 ]
# Grid-search all parameter combinations using a validation set.
opt = GridSearch(model = SVR(), param_grid = param_grid)
opt.fit(X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val)
print('Test Score for Optimized Parameters:', opt.score(X_test, y_test))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
clf = GridSearchCV(clf_,dict(C=Cs,gamma=Gammas),cv=???, # validate on X2,y2,n_jobs=8,verbose=10)
```

1. n_jobs>1 does not make any sense. If n_jobs=-1 it means the processing will use all the cores on your machine. If it is 1 only one core would be use.
2. If cv =5 it will run five cross validations for every iteration.
3. In your case total number of iterations will be 9(size of Cs)*5(Size of gammas)*5(Value of CV)

   4. If you are using cross validation it does not make any sense to hold out the data for rechecking your model. If you are not confident about the performance you can just increase the cv to get a better fit.

This will be very time consuming especially for SVM ,I will rather suggest you to use RandomSearchCV which allows you give the number of iterations you want your model to randomly select.